# When drawing a tikz custom symbol, access coordinates ratiometric to width and length

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I can do things like this in tikz, but how would I define `\wd` to be the shape width?

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]%
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
  %
  \backgroundpath{%
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa+0.5\wd}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: BTW, \wd is already defined: \wd0 is the width of \sbox0, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm this seems to work: I can add the coordinates of the northeast point to the negation of the southwest point.

```
\newdimen{\pgf@dx}
\pgfextractx{\pgf@dx}{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\southwest}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official way to obtain the width is the following

> ```
> \southwest%
> \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
> \northeast%
> \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
> ```

I am calling this official because you can see it in `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex` line 1036-1040

To obtain the north anchor, the shortest way is

> ```
> \southwest%
> \pgf@xa=.5\pgf@x%
> \northeast%
> \advance\pgf@xa by.5\pgf@x%
> ```

Comment: where is `\southwest` defined? i can't seem to use it in a saved anchor

Comment: Line 940 of the file `pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`. It is a `saveanchor`, and apparently you cannot use `saveanchor` in another `saveanchor` (Chicken or the egg). But you can look at the code for `\southwest` and `\northeast` to learn what is available.

Comment: bah, i hate having to UTSL... but thanks.

Comment: how do you know when you need `saveanchor`? The pgfdeclareshape for `rectangle` uses some but also uses regular `anchor` for things like `center` and `north`

Comment: General rule: `saveanchor`s are for optimizations and you should not use them too often. Let almost everything be `anchor`, then you can compute them using `saveanchor`s.